# How to separate user settings for multiple instances of an application (ERD)

Tags: database-design, erd

We developed a system that runs multiple instances based on a per instance configuration.

In the configuration you can define which **design** should be used for the instance, which **groups** should have access to the system, etc.

The instances (we call them *sites*) are differentiated by URL

e.g.

- abc.company.org (A)
- cde.company.org (B)
- fgh.company.org (C)

I check the current URL the user is accessing and know which configuration (design, groups) I should use for the instance.

Users can have access to multiple instances. This is checked by the groups the user is associated to, and by checking if one of the groups has access tho this instance (*site*).

This is already designed.

But now I `user_setting` should be also changeable per instance (*site*)

A user for site A has a different country, organization, title, etc. than the same user for site B (this is unfortunately the case, even if it seems illogical).

I therefore created a table called `user_settings` which stores all this information and has a foreign key to `site`. But this table would grow horizontally over time because I can not tell if the columns mentioned above are the only ones that I need in this table. Eventually we have to add 100 attributes to change it on a per site basis.

Is there probably a better way how to design this?

I am not sure if I will get into problems if I further normalize this design. e.g. create a table (green in image).

See image for better visualization:

[image]

Anybody experience with this? Suggestions are more than welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table you're considering (green in your diagram) uses an approach called **Entity Attribute Value** (EAV).  *EAV is generally considered an anti-pattern.*

You can find many, many rants about the evils of EAV using Google.  I personally believe that there is a place for EAV, and user settings might be one of them.

However, you should read up on the drawbacks of EAV before you make up your mind.

In my view, having a very wide settings table won't be that bad, especially if most users will have values set for most settings.